# FTPClient downloads a 0 byte file

Tags: java

I'm trying to download a file from a server, but it get 0 bytes...

this is my FTPDownload class

```
public boolean getFile(String filename){

        try {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

            ftpClient.connect(ftpAddress, ftpPort);
            ftpClient.login(ftpUser, ftpPass);
            int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            //FTPReply stores a set of constants for FTP reply codes. 
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
            {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                return false;

            }
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);

            String remoteFile = serverPath + filename;
            logger.debug("remote file is: "+remoteFile); //correct path
            File tempFile = new File(downloadDir+"temp.jar");
            logger.debug("file will be "+tempFile.toString()); //correctly created
            OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));

            ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile, os);
            os.close();

            String completeJarName = downloadDir+jarName;
            //delete previous file
            File oldFile = new File(completeJarName);
            FileUtils.forceDelete(oldFile);


            //rename
            File newFile = new File(completeJarName);
            FileUtils.moveFile(tempFile, newFile);

             if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                 ftpClient.logout();
                 ftpClient.disconnect();

             }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            logger.error("errore ftp", e);
            return false;
        } 

        return true;
    }
```

Basically, the temp fie gets created, then the previous file gets cancelled and the temp file renamed, but it is 0 bytes... i cannot understand where something goes wrong...

Comment: I'm not sure but try to flush the output stream `os.flush()` after `ftpClient.retrieveFile` but before `os.close()`.

Comment: you can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

i used apache.common for FTP download. here is the  code, you can try

```
 public class FTPUtils {
 private String hostName = "";
 private String username = "";
 private String password = "";
 private StandardFileSystemManager manager = null;
 FileSystemOptions opts = null;

 public FTPUtils(String hostName, String username, String password) {
  this.hostName = hostName;
  this.username = username;
  this.password = password;
  manager = new StandardFileSystemManager();
 }
     private void initFTPConnection() throws FileSystemException {
  // Create SFTP options
  opts = new FileSystemOptions();
  // SSH Key checking
  SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setStrictHostKeyChecking(
    opts, "no");
  // Root directory set to user home
  SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setUserDirIsRoot(opts, false);
  // Timeout is count by Milliseconds
  SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setTimeout(opts, 10000);
 }

 public void onUpload(String ftpfolder, String localFilePath, String fileName) {
  File file = new File(localFilePath);
  if (!file.exists())
   throw new RuntimeException("Error. Local file not found");

  try {
   manager.init();
   // Create local file object
   FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

   String remoteFilePath = "/" + ftpfolder + "/" + fileName;
   // Create remote file object
   FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(
     createConnectionString(hostName, username, password,
       remoteFilePath), opts);
   // Copy local file to sftp server
   remoteFile.copyFrom(localFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF);
   System.out.println("Done");
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // Catch and Show the exception
  } finally {
   manager.close();

  }
 }
public static String createConnectionString(String hostName,
   String username, String password, String remoteFilePath) {
  return "sftp://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + hostName + "/"
    + remoteFilePath;
 }
```

}

Comment: are you sure this is for downloading and not uploading a file to a server?

Comment: yes this is my existing code. i have used for my purpose

Answer (score 0):

BufferedOutputStream writes data to an internal buffer, so you probably need to **flush** the outputStream before closing:

```
OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile));

ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile, os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Another tips:

- Always give the Buffered streams a buffer size (typically a multiple of 8Kb).
- Always use the try-with-resources instruction when instantiating streams, and let them be automatically closed.
- Do not leave a `catch` clause without proper treatment. An exception should either *fixed* (if you want your program to recover from that exception) either *propagated* upwards (by default, propagated). Only a log is not likely to be the best treatment.